# how do I access data inside object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, local-storage

I have set a JSON object inside local storage, and am able to get it and set it inside vaccine_data state but whenever I try to call any item inside the object, am getting undefined as value.

```
//state
const [vaccine_data, setVaccine_data] = useState([]);

//localstorage data
useEffect(() => {
    setVaccine_data(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    console.log('+++--vaccine_data');
    console.log(vaccine_data);
  // console returning
/*
{"startDate":1,"endDate":7}
  });
*/
}

//inside return
return (

    {console.log('+++++',vaccine_data)} // returning data
     {vaccine_data && vaccine_data!='' && vaccine_data!=null &&(
              console.log('aaaa',vaccine_data.startDate)
            )} // returning undefined

)
```

Have provided the code that specifies my doubt, let me know if anything else is required.

Please let me know how to access inside the object. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If `vaccine_data` is an object then `if (vaccine_data)` should be enough. The tests vs. `null` and empty string are pointless.

Comment: `localStorage` stores strings. `vaccine_data` is a string. You need to JSON-decode it…?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem('data')`  returns a string. try: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))`

Comment: Will need to be paired with a `set` for updates as well using `JSON.stringify`.